Reference for the monoidal category structure $X \otimes Y = X + Y + X \times Y$ on a distributive category
Given a distributive category $\mathscr C$ (more generally a rig category), we can define a (semicocartesian) monoidal category structure on $\mathscr C$ with tensor product given by $X \otimes Y := X + Y + X \times Y$ and unit given by $I := 0$.
This monoidal structure is alluded to in several places online (e.g. this thread on the categories mailing list), but I'm having more trouble finding an explicit reference in the literature (including a proof that this does indeed define a monoidal category).
Where is this example treated? The more generality the better (e.g. it would be ideal to have a reference for the rig category case), but I would be satisfied with the case of distributive categories. (I don't even know an explicit reference for $\mathscr C = \mathbf{Set}$.) I would be even happier to have a reference in which the monoids are also characterised (I believe they ought to be the semigroups in $\mathscr C$).

The monoids are indeed the semigroups. Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5015607 (thanks for bringing me here, btw)

In Proposition 23 of Hypernormalisation in an abstract setting, Garner shows that every tricocycloid $\nu : HH \to HH$ (Definition 22 ibid.) in a symmetric distributive monoidal category $(\mathscr V, \otimes, I)$ induces a monoidal structure on $\mathscr V$ whose unit is the initial object and whose tensor product is given by:
$$A \star_\nu B := A + H \otimes A \otimes B + B$$
It is easy to verify that, given an object $H$, the symmetry $\sigma_{H, H} : H \otimes H \to H \otimes H$ exhibits a tricocycloid, and thus induces a monoidal structure $(\mathscr V, \star_H, 0)$.
The special case in which $(\mathscr V, \otimes, I) = (\mathrm{Set}, \times, 1)$ and $H = 1$ is explicitly mentioned in
Example 46 ibid.
(Garner does not consider monoids in such monoidal categories, but does consider (idempotent) commutative monoids in some particular cases.)

The monoidal product $X+Y+XHY$ doesn't require a symmetry.

True. Presumably there is a variant of Garner's statement defined in terms of $A \otimes H \otimes B$ rather than $H \otimes A \otimes B$. (Since such an approach does not seem like it would be materially different, I think Garner's proposition is a sufficient answer for my question, but it would be nice to spell out the most general statement.)
